# Regex replace text but exclude when text is between specific tag

Tags: regex

I have the following string:

```
Lorem ipsum Test dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy <a href="http://Test.com/url">Test</a> eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd sed Test dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea <a href="http://url.com">Test xyz</a> takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
```

Now I would replace the string 'Test' outside of tags an not between tags (e.g. replaced with '1234').

```
Lorem ipsum 1234 dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy <a href="http://Test.com/url">Test</a> eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd sed 1234 dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea <a href="http://url.com">Test xyz</a> takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
```

I started with this regex: `(?!<a[^>]*>)(Test)([^<])(?!</a>)`

But two problems are not solved:

1. The text 'Test' gets also replaced inside Tags (e.g. `<a href="http://Test.com/url">`)
2. Does the text between the tag not exactly match the searched text, it will be also replaced (e.g. `<a href="http://url">Test xyz</a>`)

I hope someone has a solution to solve this problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
(?!<a[^>]*?>)(Test)(?![^<]*?</a>)
```

same as zb226, but optimized with a lazy match

Also, using regexes on raw HTML is not recommended.

Comment: I also added the \b flag to match a word boundary: (?!<a[^>]*?>)(\bTest\b)(?![^<]*?</a>)

Comment: That should give the regex optimizer more to work with.  It also should not adversely affect your matches, as long as `_Test_, _Test, or Test_` are not in your document (and assuming you would not care to match them if they were).

Comment: The lookaheaed before Test and the lazy match are meaningless. See my answer.

Comment: This is not working on regexpr.com Why was this accepted?

Answer (score 26):

**Answer**

Use

```
(Test)(?!(.(?!<a))*</a>)
```

**Explanation**

Let me remind you of the meaning of some symbols:

1) `?!` is a [negative lookahead](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html), for example `r(?!d)` selects all `r` that are not directly followed by an `d`:

[image]

2) Therefore never start a negative lookahead without a character. Just `(?!d)` is meaningless:

[image]

3) The `?` can be used as a lazy match. For example `.+E` would select from

> 123EEE

the whole string `123EEE`. However, `.+?E` selects as few "any charater" (`.+`) as needed. It would only select `123E`.

***Answer:***

Protist answer is that you should use `(?!<a[^>]*?>)(Test)(?![^<]*?</a>)`. Let me explain how to make this shorter first.

As mentioned in 2), it is meaningless to put a lookahead before the match. So the following is equivalent to protist answer:

```
(Test)(?![^<]*?</a>)
```

also since `<` is not allowed, the lazy match `?` is superfluous, so its also equivalent to

```
(Test)(?![^<]*</a>)
```

This selects all `Test` that are not followed by an `</a>` without the symbol `<` in between. This is why Test which appears before or after any `<a ...> .. </a>` will be replaced.

However, note that

```
Lorem Test dolor <a href="http://Test.com/url">Test <strong>dolor</strong></a> eirmod
```

would be changed to

```
Lorem 1234 dolor <a href="http://1234.com/url">1234 <strong>dolor</strong></a> eirmod
```

In order to catch that you could change your regex to

```
(Test)(?!(.(?!<a))*</a>)
```

which does the following:

> Select every word `Test` that is not followed by a string `***</a>` where each character in `***` is not followed by `<a`.

Note that the dot `.` is important  (see 2)).

Note that a lazy match  like `(Test)(?!(.(?!<a))*?</a>)` is not relevant because nested links are illegal in HTML4 and HTML5 (smth like `<a href="#">..<a href="#">...</a>..</a>)`.

protist said

> Also, using regexes on raw HTML is not recommended.

I agree with that. A problem is that it would cause problems if a tag is not closed or opened. For example all mentioned solutions here would change

```
Lorem Test dolor Test <strong>dolor</strong></a> eirmod
```

to

```
Lorem Test dolor Test <strong>dolor</strong></a> eirmod 1234 dolores sea 1234 takimata
```

Comment: This is a brilliant solution. I would add space after <a and escape slash like this:
`(Test)(?!(.(?!<a ))*<\/a>)`

Comment: That is a solution and a great explanation. Your the winner!!!

Comment: Does not work for input "Test<a href="http://Test.com/url">Test</a>" - the first "Test" is not replaced. If you put a space character after the initial Test ("Test <a href...") it works fine. This pattern can handle it: (Test)((?!(.(?!<a))*</a>)|(?=<a))

Answer (score 6):

This should do the trick:

```
(?!<a[^>]*>)(Test)(?![^<]*</a>)
```

Try it yourself [on regexr.](https://regexr.com/50uhi)

**Follow-up:** As [Adam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2311074/adam) explains [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46937770/1529709), the first part has no effect and can be dropped entirely:

```
(Test)(?![^<]*</a>)
```

Comment: It is meaningless to put a lookahead before the match

Comment: @Adam That's of course correct, thanks for the heads up :)

Comment: This is not working on regexpr.com Why was this accepted?

Comment: @Rualark: a) This answer is not accepted and b) I don't know about the gravity of the fact that it is "not working" on some regex-page I've never heard of, and which instantly trips my company's web firewall for malicious content.

Comment: @Adam Upon revisiting this, I find that the lookahead at the beginning of the pattern is indeed crucial. That's weird because I remember testing your claim back then, and it held true! Going to try to come up with an explanation for that.

Comment: @zb226 could you provide a minimal example where it does not work?

Comment: @zb226 Sorry, I was talking about https://regexr.com/ and this answer is not accepted, seems to be not working.

Answer (score 3):

Resurrecting this ancient question because it had a simple solution that wasn't mentioned.

With all the disclaimers about using regex to parse html, here is a simple way to do it.

**Method for Perl / PCRE**

```
<a[^>]*>[^<]*<\/a(*SKIP)(*F)|Test
```

[demo](http://regex101.com/r/hU3wD2)

**General Solution**

```
<a[^>]*>[^<]*<\/a|(Test)
```

In this version, the text to be replaced is captured in Group 1 and the replacement is performed by a simple callback or lambda.

[demo](http://regex101.com/r/dI1pM2)

**Reference**

1. [How to match pattern except in situations s1, s2, s3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23589174)
2. For code implementation see the code samples in [How to match a pattern unless...](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html)

Comment: The most important part for me was to know `$replaced = preg_replace_callback(
 $regex,
 function($m) { if(empty($m[1])) return $m[0];
     else return "Superman";},
 $subject);`. So I need to return `m[0]` if `m[1]` is empty. Really nice to know. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Adapting the proposed solution by @protist, in this case searching for a phrase and **excluding** any matches inside of a script tag:

```
(?!<script[^>]*?>)(\bTest Phrase\b)(?![^<]*?<\/script>)
```

[Demo](https://regexr.com/4fa2r)

The answer provided by Adam, although more concise, takes longer to execute. This may be proven by editing the demo already mentioned in this comment.

Comment: What question are you answering?

Comment: The original question mentions "_when text is between specific tag_", my answer only broadens the solution in the event that someone needs to match against a phrase instead of a single word.

Answer (score 0):

#### in_short

For nest `<a>` case:

`(?<tagWrap><a>(?<m>(\g<tagWrap>)|.)*?<\/a>)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(Test)`

#### details

##### for excluding html `<a>` (nest)

[image: demo, case, not good] << not_good-in_nest_case

[image: demo, case, working] << working-in_nest_case

- regex

  - `((.)(?!(.(?!<a))*<\/a>))` (not_good-in_nest_case)
  - `(?!<a[^>]*?>)(.)(?![^<]*?<\/a>)` (not_good-in_nest_case)
  - `(?<!<a>(.(?!<\/a>))*?).` (not_good-in_nest_case)
  - `<a[^>]*>[^<]*<\/a(*SKIP)(*F)|.` (not_good-in_nest_case)
  - **`(?<tagWrap><a>(?<m>(\g<tagWrap>)|.)*?<\/a>)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|.`** 
    <- `<a>(?<m>(?R)|(?:.(?!<a>|<\/a>))*.)*?<\/a>` (**working**) (PCRE)
- flag: `gms`
- sample text (case when `<a>` is nested)

  ```html
  this Test this
  <a>this Test this
  <a>this Test this</a>
  this Test this</a>

  this Test this
  <a>this Test this
  <a>this Test this</a>
  this Test this</a>

  this Test this
  <a>this Test this
  <a>this Test <a>this <em>Test</em> this</a>this</a> more <a>this Test this</a>
  this Test this</a>this Test this
  ```
- explain:

  - `(?<tagWrap><a>(?<m>(\g<tagWrap>)|.)*?<\/a>)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|.` 
    -- match every character, except(/skip) the ones inside `(?<tagWrap><a>(?<m>(\g<tagWrap>)|.)*?<\/a>)`
  - `(?<tagWrap><a>(?<m>(\g<tagWrap>)|.)*?<\/a>)` 
    -- matches all the `<a>XXXXX</a>`, including nest ones
  - `(?<m>(\g<tagWrap>)|.)*?` 
    -- matches `XXXXX` inside the `<a>XXXXX</a>`, `(\g<tagWrap>)` tries to do a recursion whenever possible 

    --ie: 
    `(\g<tagWrap>)` **tries to recurse & match `<a>` whenever possible**; 
    if success, goes into another recursion; 
    if fail, `|.` matches this character -- that is not a `<a>`; 

    `*?` make sure that: \

    1. recursion `(\g<tagWrap>)` is attempt/checked for every single character inside `XXXXX`;
    2. `|.` **matches all the characters inside `XXXXX`** (- when no recursion is needed); 
       (`XXXXX` of `<a>XXXXX</a>`, but excluding the opening tags `<a>`/`</a>` -- 
       `<a>` will be matched by the (next) beginning of a recursion `BB`, 
       `</a>` will be matched by the (next) ending of a recursion `BB`);
- minor:

  - the use of `(.(?!<a>))*` to match everything, until(/break at) `<a>`, is a good hint.
- minor:

  - simple ex for recursion
  - `\((a|(?R))\)` 
    `((a))` / `(((a)))` / `((((a))))` (match these)
  - [Regular expression to match balanced parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546433/regular-expression-to-match-balanced-parentheses)

##### for excluding html comment `<!-- -->`

[image: demo, html comment] << working (3rd one)

- regex

  - `.(?!(.(?!<!--))*-->)` (not_good)
  - `(?<!<!--.*?)(.)|(.)(?!.*?-->)` (not_working)
  - **`(?<!<!--(.(?!-->))*?).`** (**working**) (Javascript regex implementation)
- flag: `gms`
- sample text (include case when comment is nested & malformed)

  ```html
  this Test this
  <!--this Test this
  <!--this Test this-->
  this Test this-->

  this Test this
  <!--this Test this
  <!--this Test this-->
  this Test this-->
  ```
- explain:

  - `(?<!<!--(.(?!-->))*?).` 
    -- match every character outside the html comment (but the `<!--` & `-->` openings still get matched...)
  - `<!--(.(?!-->))*?` match _ 1st / 1st + 2nd / 1st + 2nd + 3rd / ... _ characters starts from `<!--`, all the way, until down to `.(?!-->)` -- right before the closest `-->`.